# How do I go on to calculate time complexity of this function (f3)?

Tags: c, time-complexity

The answer is `O(n^6)` but I am not quite sure how to get there, trying with small numbers shows that g ups the number n to the power of 3 so `k=n^3` and thus `k^2=n^6` (I think), but how do I show it mathematically, specifically, we were taught a method to use a new function `T(n)` but I'm not sure how to apply it here, appreciate any help thanks.

```
int g(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    return 8 * g(n / 2);
}


void f3(int n)
{
    int k = g(n);
    for (int i = 2; i < k * k; ++i)
        {  printf("*");  }
}
```

Comment: What further "mathematics" do you need beside what you've already shown ?

Comment: I don't see how the complexity can be `O(n^6)`. The complexity of function `g` si `O(log2(n))`. The complexity of function f3 is `O((log2(n))^2)`. The approach is quite simple, from `g(n)` to `g(1)` there are `log2(n)` steps. And for function `f3` you iterate up to `k` squared, so this is where `O((log2(n))^2)`. Actually, the answer is `O(log2(n) + 64 * (log2(n))^2)` which is  `O((log2(n))^2)`.

Comment: @vasile_t Not the _time complexity_ of `g()` is relevant here, but the _growth of the result_, which is `n^3`. But see my answer below.

Comment: Ah, you derived the result of `g` experimentally, and would like to be able to derive it mathematically. Got it now :)

Comment: @Lundin This is not correct, because, as I said, the time complexity of `g()` does not play a role at all, but the _result_ of `g()`. The only relevant part is the loop iteration in `f3()`, which are `n^6` iterations.

Comment: Nevermind, gcc actually managed to unroll it, just not clang. Still, don't write code that performs badly depending on compiler.

Comment: @Lundin Interesting, but still irrelevant wrt to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first analyze the function `g(n)`:

```
g(n) = 8 * g(n/2)
```

if you eliminate the recursion, this breaks down to

```
g(n) = 8^log_2(n)
```

and eliminating the logarithm yields:

```
g(n) = n^3
```

Now `k*k` is `n^3*n^3 = n^6`, so the loop prints `n^6` asterisks. This results in the time complexity of `O(n^6)`.

Comment: @Ctx How would the complexity change  if we were to remove the k and just type it out as i<g(n)*g(n)?

Comment: @user1780131 If the function `g(n)` is really called (twice) on every iteration, then the runtime complexity of this function indeed has to be accounted for. It is `log(n)` in a uniform cost model, so the total runtime complexity is `O(n^6*log n)` then.